# ERROR: path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: r, rstudio, r-taskscheduler

Can anyone explain to me what the following error is and how I can fix it:

`ERROR: path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

It's from the RStudio add-in for the package `taskscheduleR`

Yes, I've checked other similar tickets and still can't figure it out.

Here is a picture of when/how the error gets triggered:

[image]

Here is the `traceback()`:

```
Warning: Error in normalizePath: path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
Stack trace (innermost first):
    3: shiny::runApp
    2: shiny::runGadget
    1: taskscheduleR:::taskschedulerAddin
Error : path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Edit: Other error

```
> dir(file.path(.libPaths()[1],"taskscheduleR","extdata"))
[1] "dateformat.rds"        "helloworld.R"          "RscriptRepository.rds"
> taskscheduleR::taskschedulerAddin(file.path(.libPaths()[1],"taskscheduleR","extdata"))
Loading required namespace: shiny
Loading required namespace: miniUI
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3334
Warning: Error in normalizePath: path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
Stack trace (innermost first):
    3: shiny::runApp
    2: shiny::runGadget
    1: taskscheduleR::taskschedulerAddin
Error : path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Comment: What is triggering the error?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper see my edit

Comment: please run `traceback()` just after getting the error and copy and paste (not printscreen) the output at the end of your post.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper please see the edit above

Comment: do you have 4 files in this folder: `dir(file.path(.libPaths()[1],"taskscheduleR","extdata"))` and do you have the same error when running `taskscheduleR::taskschedulerAddin(file.path(.libPaths()[1],"taskscheduleR","extdata"))`

Comment: also try updating your shiny package to latest version (and taskschedulR too of course if not done already)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Check the error message above for both requests. Also, I believe I have the most updated version seeing as there are no updates in my packages tab.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Check the error message above for both requests. Also, I believe I have the most updated version seeing as there are no updates in my packages tab.